# Call Spring mvc controller's post method from html's onclick event of button without jquery

Tags: html, spring-mvc

where i am trying to use button(not necessarily for purpose of submit) and onclick i want to call spring mvc's controller method whose requestmethod type should be POST not GET.

```
<input type="button" onClick="location.href='/result'"/>
```

This is my controller method which is being called on click.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/result")
public ModelAndView postPrintHello(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product){
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("product", product);
    model.setViewName("result");
    return model;
}
```

But when i Add RequestMethod.POST it is not called. 
Please suggest me wayout for this and also let me know if i missed something from view front.

Comment: Use a `<form>` to wrap your html data area.

Comment: Yes it is wrapped inside <form> only, for sake of simplicity i have added snipped of only <button> tag.

Answer (score 5):

try this

HTML:

```
<input type='button' value='Submit'>
```

JS:

```
$('input').on('click', function () {

   $.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url :"result",
   success: function(data) {
        console.log('success',data);
   },
   error:function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);}
}); 
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

Without JS or JQuery

```
<input type="button"  onclick="location.href='/result'" value="Submit" >
```

Note: With this way you can only send GET Request, your controller should have this annotation `method = RequestMethod.GET`

and if You want POST request without Jquery use Form

```
<form action="/result" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, we are already using action and type submit for one of our scenario, but we have this scenario, where we are having multiple buttons on same screen, where every button's click should fire different action, hence in this case, using type=submit won't suffice our requirement.

Comment: just give the actions and buttons ID's that they are connected to each other

Answer (score 0):

Either make button type submit or call javascript method and 
submit form like
document.forms["myform"].submit();

Answer (score 0):

First in form tag you have required some changes

```
    <form action="/servlet" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="login" />
    </form>
```

it will call your doPost() method